# Get rid of icon blue background in Windows App Installer

Tags: .net, packaging, winui-3

I'm developing a WinUI3 packaged application.
Now I'm trying to somehow remove blue background around the app icon that is displayed in Windows App Installer when I open the .msix package.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Can I maybe change the icon size that is used for the App Installer window?
Please help.

I'd already changed the background colour to transparent in the package manifest, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your application using a Windows 10 OS, the background around the icon will appear blue (if your background is set to transparent). Your app will also present sharp edges.

If you run your application from a Windows 11 OS, it will appear white around the icon. The windows installer will also render with rounded edges.

The assets for the application are automatically generated when you set your image in the Visual Assets of the Package Manifest, so there isn't much leeway.

I hope I helped!